# UIButton title not set until view appear

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicontrol

I create an input toolbar with `UITextView` and `UIButton`.
Just pin to the bottom of screen. Like that:

```
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return commentToolbar
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
```

When I push from other view controller. The title of `UIButton` not appear until view totally appear.

I wonder how can I set title to make its appear when controller just start pushing.

demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7k04xum12iv4bnn/BlinkSendButton.zip?dl=0

Run that demo app. Tap one cell to push new view controller. You will see the no title set to `UIButton` before view totally appeared.

[image]

Comment: can you please explain in details

Comment: Exactly what you are trying to achieve here because you are pushing same `ViewController` again and again when you click on cell

Comment: @iOS Team added GIF for this demo app. You can see the title not to be set when pushing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add...

```
inputAccessoryView?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

in your `viewDidLoad` of the ViewController.

Btw this issue appeared also to others. I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36548797/8932493